# Derivative of trace and determinant of matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I encounter a difficulty in one of my research dealing with derivative of a matrix. I will appreciate much for your expertise on this.

Let $\mathbf{x }=vec\left( X \right) $ where $X $ is a $T\times r
$ matrix of unknown parameters ($T$ and $r$ are constant, $T>>r$) and $vec$
is the vectorization, let
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}\left( \mathbf{X }\right) =\left( X ,\mathbf{I}_{T}\right) ^{\prime },  \label{def_H_theta}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{I}_T$ is $T \times T $
identity matrix. Let
\begin{equation}
\Omega \left( \mathbf{X }\right) _{T\times T}=\left( \mathbf{I}%
_{T}+XX ^{\prime }\right) .  \label{var-cov_TS_multi}
\end{equation}
What is the derivative of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \log \left\vert \Omega \left( \mathbf{X }\right)
\right\vert }{\partial \mathbf{x }}=??
\end{equation}
$|A|$ is the determinant of $A$,
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial tr\left[ \mathbf{H}\left( \mathbf{X }\right) ^{\prime
}\Omega \left( \mathbf{X }\right) ^{-1}\mathbf{H}\left( \mathbf{%
X }\right) \right] }{\partial \mathbf{x }}=??
\end{equation}
where $tr$ is the trace operator.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience, let me substitute Latin in place of your Greek letters
$$\eqalign{
 X &= \Xi \cr
 x &= \vartheta = \operatorname{vec}(X) \cr
 W &= \Omega = I + XX^T = W^T \cr\cr
}$$

Then for your first function, the differential and gradient can be calculated as 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log\det W \cr
\cr
df &= d\log\det W = d\operatorname{tr}\log W \cr
   &= W^{-T}:dW \cr
   &= W^{-T}:(dX\,X^T+X\,dX^T) \cr
   &= \big(W^{-T}X+W^{-1}X\big):dX \cr
   &= 2\,W^{-1}X:dX \cr
   &= 2\,\operatorname{vec}(W^{-1}X)\cdot\,dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,\operatorname{vec}(W^{-1}X) \cr\cr
}$$
In your second function, I don't quite understand the definition of $\,H(\vartheta)\,$ so all I can offer is a partial solution
$$\eqalign{
 M &= W^{-1} = M^T \cr
 f &= H:MH \cr
\cr
df &= dH:MH + H:M\,dH + H:dM\,H \cr
   &= (M+M^T)H:dH + HH^T:dM \cr
   &= 2\,MH:dH - HH^T:M\,dW\,M \cr
   &= 2\,MH:dH + MHH^TM:dW \cr
   &= 2\,MH:dH + MHH^TM:(dX\,X^T+X\,dX^T) \cr
   &= 2\,MH:dH + 2\,MHH^TMX:dX \cr
\cr
}$$
You can finish off the solution by expanding $dH$ in terms of $dX$, then vectorizing.

In the above, a colon denotes the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product, which is merely a product notation for the trace, i.e. $$A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

**Update**

I'm guessing that $H$ is a partitioned matrix: $H=[\,X, I\,]$

Expanding that term in the differential
$$\eqalign{
 MH:dH &= [\,MX, M\,]:[\,dX, 0\,] \cr
 &= MX:dX + M:0 \cr
}$$
So, continuing with the full differential 
$$\eqalign{
 df &= 2\,\Big(MX + MHH^TMX\Big):dX \cr
   &= 2\,\operatorname{vec}(MX + MHH^TMX)\cdot dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,\operatorname{vec}(MX + MHH^TMX) \cr
}$$

Comment: Hi, Greg, many thanks for your very detailed solution, which is very helpful. I have revised the question using your notation. The definition of H is basically a matrix containing X and an identity matrix, will this simplify the solution?

Comment: Many thanks, Greg, you are indeed very helpful. Could you please let me know your full name such that I can thank you in my paper. Thanks!!